# Star-Like Shrinking Effect For Cocos2d Transition

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game in cocos2d where I used some transition effects in replacing the scene, such as `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[MyScene node]]];`.

But in one stage I want to show a transition effect like in [this example](http://screencast.com/t/EB9Zq2wtis). That is some star-like shrinking effect to replace the scene. I tried many transition effects but none of them match the effect which I mentioned above. Is there a default transition effect to achieve this or do I need to customize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can simply use white texture with transparent star in the center of it. And then just scale it to show/hide your scene.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try to implement it as you said.